# C# inheritance and constructors and overide

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm testing this program for inheritance I have 3 classes ( animal,emu,kangaroo)
and main class.

emu and kangaroo derived from Animal class.

when I try to run the program getting error Emu.Bird(), Kangaroo.Mamel() is not suitable method found to overide. I'm doing it by a random tutorial and not sure about the "override" and what exactly it does.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Emu e = new Emu("Emu","Brown", "is a bird");

        Console.WriteLine();

        Kangaroo k = new Kangaroo("Kangaroo","Dark Brown", "Is a mamel" );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Animal Class

```
 class Animal
{
    public string name;
    public string colour;

    public Animal(string MyName,string MyColour)
    {
        name = MyName;
        colour = MyColour;
    }

    public virtual void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: "+ name);
        Console.WriteLine("Colour: "+ colour);

    }
}
```

Emu Class

```
 class Emu:Animal
{
    public string bird;

    public Emu(string name,string colour, string eBird) : base(MyName,MyColour)
    {
        bird = eBird;
    }

    public override void Bird()
    {
        base.Show();
        Console.WriteLine(bird);
    }

}
```

Kangaroo Class

```
  class Kangaroo:Animal
{
    public string mamel;


    public Kangaroo(string name,string colour, string Mamel) : base(MyName,MyColour)
    {
        mamel = Mamel;
    }

    public override void Mamel()
    {
        base.Show();
        Console.WriteLine("Is a bird or Mamel ? " + mamel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your *first* problem is in terms of your use of `base`in the constructor declaration - in each case it should be `base(name, colour)`

Comment: The next problem is that you're trying to override a method that doesn't exist - you can't do that, and it doesn't make sense. Perhaps you should be overriding `Show` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The word override in coding means to replace the implementation of an existing  method, i.e overriding the previous method.

So here in your case, the class that you are inheriting from doesn't have mamel or bird method.

Don't just read random articles..go by series of topics. Refer a book or some tutorial series.

Check if you can pdf version of **CLR via C#** 
or you can also refer our ongoing tutorial series at [CheezyCode](http://www.cheezycode.com/p/c-tutorial-with-examples.html)